# ¿Cambio de Screen en Kivy Python?

Tags: python, kivy

me gustaría usar una función en Kivy desde un botón en otro widget para hacer un cambio de screen, el problema es que la función sí es realizada y no marca ningún tipo de error, pero no hace el cambio de screen.
En la clase Principal, quiero que cambie de screen con la función About(),pero no realiza el cambio ya que quiero que la función sea realizada desde otro Layout, específicamente desde el Layout Banner()
La variable Current sí cambia, pero no hace el cambio de Screen

```
class Principal(ScreenManager):
def __init__(self):
    super(Principal, self).__init__()
    self.add_widget(Screen01())
    self.add_widget(About())
    self.current = "Inicio"
def About(self, *arg):
    self.current = "About"

class Screen01(Screen):
def __init__(self):
    super(Screen01, self).__init__()
    self.name = "Inicio"
    self.add_widget(Content01())

class Banner(BoxLayout):
  def __init__(self):
        super(Banner, self).__init__()
        self.AcercaDe = Button(font_size = 20, text= 'Acerca De', background_color = [1,1,1,0])
        self.Inicio = Button(font_size=20, text='Inicio', background_color=[1, 1, 1, 0])
        self.add_widget(self.Inicio)
        self.add_widget(self.AcercaDe)
        self.Inicio.bind(on_press = self.Iniciopress)
  def Iniciopress(self, *arg):
    Prince = Principal()
    Principal().About()
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor realiza el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Por favor agrega el código como texto para que sea mas manejable en lugar de la imagen, te invito a editar la pregunta y eliminar la imagen y colocar el código como texto.

Comment: muestra tu codigo como texto, lee [ask] y pasa el [tour]